# Open Particular app page after click on push notification using onesignal and nativescript

Tags: push-notification, nativescript, onesignal, nativescript-vue

I want to open particular component of nativescript app when user click on push notification sent by onesignal.
How to do this using nativescrip-vue and onesignal??

Comment: You will have to initiate the navigation based on the data you get form push notification on the notification callback.

Comment: Can you tell me sample code for that??

Answer (score -1):

If the notification callback is defined inside a vue component, you can call [`this.$navigateTo`](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/#navigatetocomponent-options) to navigate to any page.